# How can I get an IUpdateEntry from a DbContext for a object that is read?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to create a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` and pass it the `IUpdateEntry` for the object I just had returned by `dbContext.Events.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == entity.Id)`

I am throwing it if the `rowversion` has been updated over the value when the object was first read in when initializing a web page.

Comment: EF has its own optimistic concurrency check. Not sure what you're doing here and why that requires access to an EF interface that's clearly not intended for usage in application code.

Comment: @GertArnold I read in the model object when I populate a page and save that object. The user makes their edits and clicks save. At this point I read the object in again so I can apply the changes and save it. On that re-read I want to throw a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` if the underlying object has been modified by another.

Comment: Well, if you do it on save, EF will do everything for you if you configure optimistic concurrency.

Comment: @GertArnold What I found is, as I have to create a new DbContext (can't save one between page initialization and page submit), is it was very difficult to apply the old model object to the new DbContext, and then telling it to track any value I then change. A re-read works perfectly. But in that re-read, I have to compare the rowversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick search in EF Core code yields this solution:

```cs
var updateEntry = (IUpdateEntry)((IInfrastructure<InternalEntityEntry>)dbContext.Entry(event)).Instance;
```

Comment: Thank you. I spent probably an hour yesterday trying to find something like this and failed.